# Unable to print a char* string

Tags: c, string, printf

It's not clear to me what's wrong with my program, it's a simple code to open a file, read the first line from it, and then print it. But the program keeps crashing. The actual content of my text file is a sentence: Test my code.

```
int main(void)
{
FILE *stream;
char *s;
stream = fopen("input.txt", "r");
fscanf(stream, " %s", &s);

printf("%s", s);


fclose(stream);
return 0;
}
```

I'm instructed not to use the library functions found in `<string.h>`

Comment: 1. You don't check the result of `fopen`. 2. `s` is an uninitialized pointer - where do you thing the data goes?

Comment: `char s[16]; fgets(s, sizeof s, stream);` instead of `char *s;...fscanf(stream, " %s", &s);`

Comment: If you're using GCC, always compile with `gcc -Wall -Werror`.

Comment: `char *s; ... fscanf(stream, " %s", &s);` --> `char s[100]; fgets(s, sizeof s, stream);`

Answer (score 3):

`s` is an uninitialized pointer.  You need to allocate some memory for `fscanf` to write into.

Comment: I initialized it as: char *s = NULL; but the program still crashes

Comment: That doesn't provide any memory to write into.

Comment: You can use either memory on the stack (`char s[10]` allocates 10 characters on the stack) or use dynamic memory allocation with malloc.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you are missing in your code.

```
// Uninitialise pointer, you need to allocate memory dynamically with malloc before you use it. That is
char *s;
int size = 20;  // size of the string you want
s = malloc(size * sizeof(char));

// Or you can use a VLA and with this you don't have to use free(s)

char s[20];


// fopen could fail, always check the return value before using it.
stream = fopen("input.txt", "r"); 

if(stream == NULL){
  perror("File opening failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
fscanf(stream, "%s", s);


//Don't forget to do free(s) to free memory allocated with malloc .  when you are done with it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *s;
```

Allocates the number of bytes needed for holding a memory address (on most systems 32/64 bits).
But since you are not initializing the pointer, its value (the address it **points** to) is undefined.

Ergo: fscanf tries to write to an undefined memory address.

> I initialized it as char *s = NULL;

Yes, the pointer is now initialized (yay!) but now points to nowhere.

Ergo: fscanf will try to write to nothing.

The solution is to allocate some memory fscanf can use. 
fscanf does not magically allocate memory for you!

You can use either stack memory or dynamic allocated memory (heap).

Stack memory is easier to manage but is much smaller than the heap.

Here a solution which uses memory on the stack:

```
// Allocates 10 bytes on the stack
// Given 1 Character = 1 Byte the
// buffer can hold up to 9 characters.
char myBuffer[10];

// Initialize s with the address of myBuffer
char *s = myBuffer;

// Call fscanf
fscanf(stream, "%9s", s);
```

You may be wondering why I used `%9s` instead of `%s`.

The reason is to prevent a buffer overflow:

fscanf does not know how big the buffer is, so you need to tell it.

Otherwise fscanf will write data beyond your allocated memory.

I suggest you read up on C strings and memory management in general.

Comment: `fscanf(stream, "%9s", s);` does not read a _line_ of input well.  `%s` does not save white-space.  A line like `"1 2 3"` will not get read into `s` as `"1 2 3"`

Comment: @chux Neat observation. Didn't know that :)